# Using lookup function to return list of values with filtering

Tags: vba, excel

I am currently using lookup function to return multiple values. I got this function from Extend Office. 
https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2706-excel-vlookup-return-multiple-values-in-one-cell.html

I want to edit the codes to cater to my needs where it can further filter the multiple values to only what I need. I am currently using Instr Function to return only values that start with whatever the alphabet  the user keys in. However, the function cannot work as the result would show '#VALUE!'. I have no idea where I have gone wrong.

For example I use key in the function in the sheet itself, 'MYVLOOKUP(C2,Table!A:B,2,"J")'. This means that I only want to return values starting with 'J' but it returns #VALUE!.

```
Function MYVLOOKUP(pValue As String, pWorkRng As Range, pIndex As Long, 
filter As String)
Dim rng As Range
Dim xResult As String
Dim result As Integer

xResult = vbNullString
'the next line trims pWorkRng down to the .UsedRange
Set pWorkRng = Intersect(pWorkRng, pWorkRng.Parent.UsedRange)

For Each rng In pWorkRng
    If rng = pValue Then
        result = InStr(rng.Value, filter, vbTextCompare)
        If result = 1 Then
        xResult = xResult & rng.Offset(0, pIndex - 1) & ","
        Else
        End If
   End If
Next
MYVLOOKUP = Trim(xResult)
End Function
```

Comment: Please elaborate on *"cannot work"* and show an example use-case.

Comment: You first check `If rng = pValue` and then if it starts with `filter`, this double check doesn't make sense. Either search for an exact match or for something that starts with something.

Comment: I can't return multiple values where it reduces the range of the values to only starting with let say 'J' ?

Comment: Yes but that is already feasible with the built-in `VLOOKUP`. I don't get what's the special thing you want to achieve with this custom UDF.

Comment: Because the values that is return is a lot and I want to reduce the range of the return values.

Comment: So the only difference with `VLOOKUP` is that you want to return a list, not the first match, right?

Comment: Yeah and from that list of values, I want to return only values starting with 'J'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you are seeking this UDF:

```
Function MYVLOOKUP(pValue As String, pWorkRng As Range, pIndex As Long, _
                   Optional filter As String = "*")
  Dim rng As Range, ret As String
  For Each rng In Intersect(pWorkRng.Columns(1), pWorkRng.Parent.UsedRange)
    If rng Like pValue Then If rng(1, pIndex) Like filter Then _
      ret = ret & IIf(Len(ret), ",", "") & rng(1, pIndex)
  Next
  MYVLOOKUP = ret
End Function
```

Notice how to use it:

- the first parameter is an exact match on the first column. You can use **wildcards (*)** inside, such as `"xx*"` to match anything starting with `"xx"`, or `"*yy*"` to match anything containing `"yy"`.
- the last parameter is a similar filter but on the returned values. Hence you can use `"J*"` to limit the returned values to those starting with `"J"`. This parameter is **optional:** you can omit it if you don't want any filtering.
- the returned value is a comma-separated list of all the matches found.

Example:

[image]

Comment: @RachelChia use `"J*"` for "start with J", ` `"*J"` for "ends with J", and  `"*J*"` for "contains J" :)